# Паттерны JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.

Может кто знает хорошую книгу по паттернам `JavaScript`, ссылки на хорошие статьи с советами, как строить большие системы. В интернете, конечно, много всего, но хотелось бы сразу отбросить всю шелуху и услышать совет, какие из всех источников хороши для изучения паттернов на `JavaScript`.

А то совсем от рук отбился. Тяжело строить систему на JavaScript, когда под рукой нет хорошего справочника для построения больших систем.

PS.
Я, конечно, знаю, что есть книги по паттернам для Java, C++, книга банды четырех, но хотелось бы именно с примерами построения только на `JavaScript`.

Comment: Естественно книга должна быть написана для Javascript т.к. Javascript - очень сильно отличается от Java и C++ и, наверное, как "ник-то другой" меньше всего на них похож.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вот собственно [книга](http://bheinrichs.nl/Files/design%20patterns/APress_ProJavaScriptDesignPatterns.pdf)( язык - английский ) - лучшее из всего что я когда либо находил на эту тему. Но читать ее имеет ИМХО смысл при уже сформировавшемся понимании языка. Надеюсь это то что вы искали.

---

Немного лир.отступления. Из всего проведенного мною времени за изучением и написанием кода - я сделал вывод, что  JavaScript, как не парадоксально - один из самых гибких, язык - простой и крайне сложный(по началу, в некоторых местах мне даже Java, С++ казались намного более простыми языками, причиной этому, конечно-же, было - непонимание). ИМХО решающим фактором в легкости написания и построения большего JavaScript кода является, все-таки, мозг + опыт и, что, наверное главное, **понимание языка** ибо без этого хорошим JavaScript программистом стать ИМХО - невозможно и писать хороший, большой, структурированый код, естественно, тоже. Эту "речь" я написал к тому, что JavaScript нужно учить, по большей части на практике а не в теории( все языки лучше учить на практике, но что касается js - зачастую нет другого выбора ), основной причиной тому является ужасная литература, в том числе - *непонимание языка* автором и многое многое другое. И напоследок 2 совета при написании любого javascript кода - используйте "пространство имен", используйте объекты и замыкание - они дают великие возможности.

---

PS:любите JavaScript таким каким он есть =). С наступающим...

Comment: Читаю Дэвида Флэнагана - Javascript. Издательство O'Reilly. Написано для людей с небольшим багажом в программировании. Очень исчерпывающая информация.

Comment: Что касается javascript (парадокс, но тем не менее) - лучше всего подойдет видео лекции Дугласа Крокфорда, просто идем на youtube, вбиваем 'javascript crockford' и, если у вас все более менее с английским - смотрим и наматываем на ус.

Реально по javascript за все время читал 3 книги( всего читал 10+ ) это "JavaScript: Подробное руководство"(ИМХО единственная адекватная книга для изучения javascript), книга про HTML5 canvas(сейчас не вспомню как называлась) и "Pro JavaScript Design Patterns" издательства Apress.

А вы уверены в том что эта книга действительно хороша? :DDD

Comment: Есть же ещё и Стефан Стоянов, "JavaScript. Шаблоны", даже на русский язык переведена: http://www.books.ru/books/javascript-shablony-827259/

Comment: ОГО! Спасибо за хороший ответ и сопутствующий совет!